# Mongoose- How to use "where" clause after populate and filtering

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have two Models - product and Category

CategoryId is inside each product Object (Which is referring to _id in Category).

**Category Looks like this:**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f3564489dc78d423f75af3d"),
    "category": "OVEN",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Product Looks like this

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f36dd21ee0c6c27c04903cc"),
    "categoryId": ObjectId("5f358007159810587d26ee5e"),
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want products & I want to do these things in order before getting them:

**1. populate categoryId.**

**2. filter out only required categoryId.**

**3. Performing limit, skip.**

*How can I do this?*

**THIS IS HOW I AM DOING IT CURRENTLY**

```
Product.find({})
        .populate({
          path: "categoryId",
          options: {
          limit: limitProductsOnPage,
          sort: { rank: 1 },
          skip: (page - 1) * limitProductsOnPage
         },
      })
       .exec(function(err, products) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error Occured", err);
             }

     let filteredProducts;//to Store Filtered Products
                                

     filteredProducts = products.filter(product=> { (#POINT-1)
                                        
          if(product.categoryId._id.toString() == category_id){
                       return product;
          }
      });
 }
```

*The main problem here is that I am filtering(#POINT-1) after limit and skip! Whereas, filtering must be done before.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do all that in one query, filtering out the specific category id by by using `$ne`. Doing something like:

```
Product.find({categoryId: {$ne: category_id})
    .sort({ rank: 1 })
    .limit(limitProductsOnPage)
    .skip((page - 1)* limitProductsOnPage)
    .populate("categoryId")
```

This should have the required behaviour that you want although it will not be doing it in the exact order that you want.